# Open Data formats used

Tags: data-request, data-format, 5-star-scheme

I would like to know if there is any kind of official study with the OD formats used to publish datasets worldwide with respective percentage.

Comment: Percentages get really messy as you have to ask what the units are -- by volume (number of bytes)?  by a count of the files?  By the number of '[datasets](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3491/263)'? If a file is mirrored in 3 places, is it counted 3 times, or once?  What if they are recalibrated versions of the same initial observation?  If we're counting by 'dataset', and the data's available in more than one packaging, how do we weight each package?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about worldwide, but for Europe you can find statistics on data formats on the [ENGAGE portal](http://www.engagedata.eu/opendatasites).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Open Knowledge Foundation (OKFN) published a study it did on government data portals around the world. A number of different variables (criteria) were used. I don't recall data formats as one of them, but if not you still might be able to reverse engineer from their study data.

https://okfn.org/about/our-impact/open-data-index/